# Getting audio to play on item pickup in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a sound effect when I pick up an item. I have the audio source component, and I have the sound clip assigned. I get no errors and everything seems to be working, but I still do not get sound when I pick up the item. My script:

```
    public ParticleSystem pickupEffect;

public float speedPercentDrop = 50f; // 10% chance
public GameObject speedPowerUp;

public float healthPercentDrop = 70f; // 70% chance
public GameObject healthPowerUp;

private AudioSource puAudio;

public void Start()
{
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        puAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        puAudio.Play();
        Pickup(other);
        
    }
}

void Pickup(Collider player)
{
    
    Debug.Log("Picked Up");
    Destroy(gameObject);


}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the variant of [Destroy (Object, delay)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), passing in the duration of the clip as the second argument, so the object doesn't gets destroyed before completing the sound effect!!!! Seems like you destroying the `gameObject` and as it has the `AudioSource` on it which gets destroyed too.

Comment: @nIcEcOw that works! But is there a way to make it so that there isn't a delay like that? I have Destroy(gameObject, 1), and there's still that very small delay. But I would like that delay to be as small as possible

Comment: The object carrying the `AudioSource` should be a separate game object. The delay in Destroy is just to convey to you what is happening with this `AudioSource` as you destroy the game object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to delay your object destroying.

1. Create an empty object as the item child
2. Attach your audio to the child
3. Before destroying the item, change the child parent to null => `transform.GetChild(0).transform.parent = null;`

So in the end, your "PickUp" method should look like this:

```
void Pickup(Collider player)
{
    Debug.Log("Picked Up");
    Transform _child = transform.GetChild(0);
    _child.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    _child.parent = null;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: UnityException Transform Child out of bounds

Comment: @ANewProgrammer  Your object in the hierarchy must be like this ->  [Image](https://i.postimg.cc/MTWgJ3bY/Screenshot-2021-11-22-233447.png) Did you put it under the item as its child? if so you shouldn't receive this error.